# Git cherry-pick - How to display changes without actually doing anything

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

Is there any way to display changes that would be applied by the 'git cherry-pick ' before actually doing anything?

I would like to see a 'git diff' type of list of changes that would be done by the command without actually doing the changes or modifying anything.

Comment: The obvious suggestion is "git diff", which you've already mentioned, but I'm guessing you're passing more than just a single commit to the cherry-pick command? Perhaps you could give an example.

Comment: Remember also that `git show`, used on an ordinary (single-parent) commit, shows the same diff that `git cherry-pick` will attempt to apply to your *current* commit. So if you are thinking "I might like commit `a123456`, let me see what it does" you would run `git show a123456` to see what it does. Then you'd decide whether to attempt the cherry-pick.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of git show (that's what I have been using currently) but I would also like to see directly what are the lines the cherry-pick will replace/change.

Answer (score 8):

`git cherry-pick` doesn't have a `--dry-run` option like some other commands.

However, although not exactly what you asked, you could just test it out by leveraging the [`-n` (`--no-commit`) option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt--n).

The rollback would be trivial :

*(assuming you start on a clean working tree)*

```
# cherry-pick without actually committing
git cherry-pick -n <commit>

# inspect changes
git diff --staged

# wipe all these temporary changes to go back to where you started
git reset --hard
```

Comment: This is the answer I was afraid to get but thanks anyway. I wanted to avoid reset --hard if possible

Comment: After `git reset --hard`, `git status` returned `Cherry-pick currently in progress. (run "git cherry-pick --continue" to continue) ...`.Running that `--continue` command brought back everything as it was before the `git cherry-pick -n <commit>`.

Comment: Turns out that (at least with git version `2.39.1`) the `git reset --hard` execution is not required at all; `git cherry-pick --abort` will bring back the state as before the `git cherry-pick -n <commit>` execution.

Answer (score 3):

I've done such "experiments" on a (temporary) branch. Original master/main is left unchanged.

```
git checkout -b cherry-test
git cherry-pick <sha1>
git show/log/whatever
git checkout master
git branch -D cherry-test
```

Answer (score 0):

I Believe  you can do a git diff between the last commit on your branch and the commit you want to cherry-pick like so :

git diff [last-commit-hash] [cherry-pick-commit-hash]

Comment: Is this actually the same as doing cherry-pick? this diffs everything in the repo, cherry-pick just merges the changes in single commit not everything in the repo. I'm not going to do a full merge, I'm doing cherry-pick for a reason.